# Skip row that results in zero

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to skip all rows that result in zero after division. For example

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|    5 |    5 |    
|    3 |    0 |    
|   12 |    6 |
+------+------+
```

Then `col3 = col1 /col2` giving:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    5 |    5 |    1 |
|   12 |    6 |    2 |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: `where col2 <> 0` would avoid divide by zero which is not the same as "result in zero after division". Technically for that you can only have zero in the numerator for that result. You might also have wanted `col1 / nullif(col2, 0)` which doesn't "skip" the row, it just avoids the division error by treating is as a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select col1, col2, col1/col2
from tablename
where col2!=0
```